# "Our" class teacher or "my" class teacher?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, possessives

I have to write this in my project acknowledgment:

> I am sincerely thankful to **my** class teacher ...

But, the class teacher is not mine alone, she's of all the students of the class. But then, this project is mine alone, not everyone's.

I am not able to grasp this. What should I write: "my" or "our" ? Both the above facts have equal weightage too. Please help me overcome this confusion.

I saw [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6702/my-mom-or-our-mom) on duplicate list but it isn't related in this context.

Thanks!

Comment: One can say 'my father' even if he has a brother. Likewise, in this case, you can say either 'our teacher' or 'my teacher'. They're both fine. 'Our' may be more appropriate if you're not speaking only about yourself but your whole group, for example if you're talking as a representative for your whole class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct in their own senses.

> I am sincerely thankful to my/our class teacher.

And as for your question about the project being your own, the subject that we speak of in the sentence is not the *project* but the *teacher*, and as such your class teacher is the teacher of all her students, not just you.

If the subject were a project, like:

> I am thankful to everyone who contributed towards *my* project.

Here, we would use *my* instead of *our* because it is solely your project, not that of the class or a group of students.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Invoker's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/23698/6407), the context of the conversation also influences whether you use *my* or *our*.

If you are speaking to someone who shares your teacher, you would use *our*. For example:

> Did you enjoy today's lecture? I thought *our* teacher did a good job.

In this context, it is not semantically correct to use *my*, as it implies that your classmate does not actually have the same teacher as you, which is false.

If you are speaking to someone not in your class, you would typically use *my*. For example:

> What happened at school today? *My* class's teacher gave a lecture to the entire student body.

Here, using *my* is technically semantically more correct. However, using *our* is acceptable, because it's understood that *our* is used to convey membership in a larger group (the class) rather than meaning that the listener also shares your teacher.

Finally, note the slight changes I have made to the phrase in question: *our teacher* and *my class's teacher*. These are American English idiomatic phrasings. *Class* is omitted because it's understood, or changed to the possessive because that's simply the construction of choice. In the latter case, the emphasis is on *class*, which has a teacher, hence the possessive. *Class teacher* is both perfectly grammatical and the idiomatic phrasing of choice in British English.